# What is the most robust way to assert for a validation error?

Tags: testing, forms

I want to test the validation function in my custom module, and so I've written a simpletest that inputs an illegal value in a field and then attempts to save the node. Currently I'm using `assertText()` to find the string contained in the validation failure message on the page, but if someone changes the wording of the failure message in the future, this could break. Is there a more robust way to check that a field, or even a node save generally, failed validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution, for Drupal 7.

```
try {
  custom_validation();
  // if validation passes incorrectly then:
  this->fail("Validation should have failed, but didn't");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->assertEqual('Expected error message', $e->getMessage, 'Test successful message');
}
```

Use `\Exception $e` in Drupal 8.

Thanks to dawehner on #drupal-contrib for [help with this](https://gist.github.com/dawehner/5517263).

Comment: When I do this it does work (i.e. it doesn't think it's a failing test, and it does run the code), but it never displays 'Test successful message' or anything at all about the assertion.

Comment: Hey @beth, see the addition I just made. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: Does that mean that this only works in Drupal 8, or that it requires the modification of using \Exception $e in Drupal 8 but works without it in Drupal 7?

Comment: The latter. The code should work in D7, or in D8 with the modification.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking of custom validation, if the code is using [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) or [form_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_error/7), then there should not be any problem, if the test code and the form validation handler use the same string (which is passed / not passed to `t()` in both the cases).

Keep in mind that the modules enabled during a test execution are Drupal core modules enabled from the profile used for the tests, or modules explicitly enabled from the test class. The error message output from your form validation handler is not altered, if the modules enabled from the test class don't alter it.

An alternative method of checking if a validation handler returned an error would be setting a global variable, for example; that is something Drupal does, but only from a module that is used only for testing, not a module that is normally executed. For example, [entity_crud_hook_test_comment_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!tests!entity_crud_hook_test.module/function/entity_crud_hook_test_comment_delete/7) (the implementation of [hook_comment_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_delete/7) done from the [Entity CRUD Hooks Test](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!tests!entity_crud_hook_test.module/7) module) uses a session variable that is set when the hook is invoked.
Notice that this is what Drupal normally does to verify a hook is effectively invoked when it should. When you need to verify if a form validation handler returned an error, I would rather use the method you are using, since:

- It doesn't require the form validation handler to know if it is being executed during test, or not
- It doesn't require the use of a test module

There are some cases where a module needs to be created with the only purpose of testing something, but that is not generally the case of verifying a form validation handler effectively returns an error when it should.

Comment: Yes I am using form_set_error() and you are right, it works. My question was whether there was a way to detect validation failure generally rather than a specific error message.

Comment: I am going to answer that point too; I first need to find an example of code used by Drupal.